# Is it necessary to historically lock a question about HTML Imports given that HTML Modules will be recommended in a year or three?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

Thanks for **historically locking**:

[On what specific grounds were HTML Imports rejected, deprecated and removed?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127482/on-what-specific-grounds-were-html-imports-rejected-deprecated-and-removed)

But, is it strictly necessary?

I can foresee a time in the not-too-distant future when **HTML Modules** are finally completed and become a recommended standard, at which point an answer (either from me or another Webmasters SE member) confirming as much will be the definitive, accepted answer.

This is the primary reason why, to date, I have not accepted an answer on the question.

All views welcome.

I trust that, given that:

- the question is pertinent to Webmastering, focusing on which browsers support (or have supported in the past) client-side functionality to enable importing markup into a current document
- the question has 17 upvotes

it will generally be quite welcome as an open question on Webmasters SE.

Answer (score 3):

I locked that question as it really is more of a web development question as opposed to a "running a website" question. It isn't really on-topic here but due to its popularity I didn't want to close or remove it.

This question probably should have been asked on/migrated to the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site where questions like this are on-topic.

Comment: Fair enough. Yes, I shall be happy for the question to be moved over to **Software Engineering** if that means the question can be kept open. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the window for migrating is closed. I think a question can only be migrated within two months of being asked.

Comment: Then I'd respectfully request that the question not be closed, please. I'd submit there is nothing to be gained by censoring further updates on such a question. Webmasters do need to be aware of browser functionality and I'd want to propose that client-side HTML Importing is a pretty significant piece of browser functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately it just is not on-topic here. If having this question be open at any site is important to you, you could send an email to the nice folks at the Stack Exchange and make a request to have this moved to the Software Engineering Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I am trying to send a nice communication to the moderators and members of Webmasters MSE to make the case, persuasively, that a functionality such as _HTML Importing_ falls under _Browser Engine Capability_ which is a concern of Webmasters. Nobody else has joined this discussion so far. I also recognise that you are in a position to make rulings and I am not. Nevertheless, I appeal in good faith.

Comment: I note the question has now received more than 3000 views. **HTML Imports** are arguably quite a popular consideration for webmasters, many of whom will regard the future browser capability of importing HTML into a web document as entirely on-topic. How may I successfully appeal the decision to suspend this question on _SE Webmasters_ and enable this question's status to be updated from _off-topic_ to _on-topic_? Many thanks.